# free reports bogus amount of swap used

Tags: linux, memory, rhel6, bug

The swap used reported by free is very high.

```
[root@rhel6 ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          9892       9537        354          0         71        884
-/+ buffers/cache:       8581       1310 
Swap:          767 1759218592     116869
```

Like, *really* high.

```
[root@bb14 blackboard]# free -g|grep Swap
Swap:            0 1717986906        114
```

Or is it?

```
[root@bb14 blackboard]# free -h |grep Swap
Swap:         767M       767M       114G
```

Even more strange, even if I disable swap the number still stays high.

```
[root@rhel6 ~]# swapoff -a
[root@rhel6 ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          9892       9760        131          0         45        638
-/+ buffers/cache:       9076        815 
Swap:            0 1759218592     116814
```

Things don't get any less confusing when checking meminfo, which shows swapfree higher than swaptotal.

```
[root@rhel6 ~]# cat /proc/meminfo|grep Swap
SwapCached:            0 kB
SwapTotal:        786428 kB
SwapFree:       120404008 kB
```

Obviously something is wonky and my first instinct is to reboot, but this is a production machine which means maintenance windows, etc, and I'm wondering if there's any way to find out what's wrong and possibly even fix it without downtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to Upgrade to *kernel-2.6.32-573.7.1.el6* or higher.

A simple `yum update` and reboot should be all it takes.

Below is a quote of the bug report of *kernel-2.6.32-573.1.1.el6.x86_64* that caused the Swap free to be greater than the swap total:

> A previous change in the get_swap_page() locking removed the use of
>   the swap_lock spinlock. This could cause nr_swap_pages corruption and
>   invalid SwapFree information in the /proc/meminfo file, where the size
>   of SwapFree could exceed the size of SwapTotal. This update uses an
>   atomic variable for nr_swap_pages, and the size of SwapFree in
>   /proc/meminfo is now correct. (BZ#1259362)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a known issue in RHEL6.7 with kernel-2.6.32-573.1.1.el6.x86_64 being tracked in their private bugzilla.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1571043